# ¿Como mostrar las opciones selecionadas de un Select en PHP?

Tags: php, html, select

tengo un problema con un Select donde quiero selecionar mas de una opcion pero no se como mostrar lo que e selecionado, e buscado por internet y no encuentro nada, ahora bien logre mostrar solo la primera opcion del Selcet pero no es lo que necesito, paso codigo por aca:

Codigo PHP del Select:

```
<label class="d-flex " for="zona">Zonas:
  <select class="select-css parte_zona" name="Zona" id="" multiple required>
    <?php foreach ($zona as $dato6) { ?>
      <option id="Zona" value="<?php echo $dato6->NOMBRE_ZONA ?>"><?php echo $dato6->NOMBRE_ZONA ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
  </select>
</label>
```

Paso Codigo de como lo muestro:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-row pe-lg-3 mb-2">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <i title="Zona" style="color:yellow;" class=" icon_agrandar  fas fa-child"></i>
    <span class="icon_subir ps-1">&nbsp<?php echo $dato->ZONA ?></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Consulta a la base de datos:

```
$consulta6 = $con->query("SELECT * FROM zona;");
$zona = $consulta6->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Funcion de $dato:

```
$x = 0;
while ($x < 25) {
  $turnosFiltrados = array_filter($turno, function ($dato) use ($hora_s, $x, $sucursalDrop, $PROfesional, $fecha) {
    return ($dato->HORA_INICIO == $hora_s[$x]) && ($dato->NOMBRE_SUCURSAL == $sucursalDrop) && ($dato->FECHA == $fecha) && ($dato->PROFESIONAL == $PROfesional);
  });
  
  if ($turnosFiltrados) {
    foreach ($turnosFiltrados as $dato)
```

Si se necesita mas codigo o algo mas de descripcion me avisan por los comentarios, Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Al igual que en el select usas un bucle foreach, debes hacer lo mismo en el código que luego muestras, pero poco podremos ayudarte si no pones el código de lo que es $dato->ZONA para ver como lo sacas, pues alli debes tener la otra parte del problema

Comment: Claro @masterguru, ahi te muestro de donde sale ese $dato y tambien la consulta a la base de datos

Comment: cuando recibes Zona de lado del servidor debe ser un array de datos no un string valida que informacion estas recibiendo en el backend y asegurate de haber seleccionado varios.

Comment: heee, perdon no entendi lo que tu me dices @ArcanisGK507

Comment: como que no entiendes lo que te digo ... son termino de programacion... a ver dime que no entiendes???

Comment: no entiendo que seria "un string valido que informacion estas recibiendo en el backend"

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así, el truco está en los `[]` de `name="cars[]"`:

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['cars']))
    echo '<pre>'.print_r($_GET,true).'</pre>';

echo '
    <form>
    <select name="cars[]" id="cars" multiple>
      <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
      <option value="saab">Saab</option>
      <option value="opel">Opel</option>
      <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
    <div><button>Seleccionar</button></div>
    </form>
';
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]